# How do you make speech bubble with Tooltipsy?

Tags: css, tooltip

I'm trying to use [Tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/) to make tool tips for my site. I'd like to use the "speech tooltip" style shown on the homepage, but can't find any instructions on how to implement that, and when I try to track it down in the page source code  and css I end up with a speech bubble with no little triangle thing at the bottom. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question as you, but I have looked up in the code source of the Tootipsy web page... and finded how to do!

Here is the javascript call

```
$('.hastip').tooltipsy({
    className: 'bubbletooltip_tip',
    offset: [0, 10],
    show: function (e, $el) {
        $el.fadeIn(100);
    },
    hide: function (e, $el) {
        $el.fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

And the css:

> .bubbletooltip_tip
>   {
>       padding: 10px;
>       color: #fff;
>       background-color: #222;
>       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
>       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
>       box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
>       text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
>       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
>       -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
>       border-radius: 10px;
>       position: relative;
>   }
>
> .bubbletooltip_tip:after
>   {
>       content: '';
>       position: absolute;
>       border: 10px solid transparent;
>       border-left-color: #000;
>       top: -10px;
>       right: 40px;
>       z-index: -1;
>   }

I hope I've helped you.